# Mobx 6 observable not working correctly with mobx-router5

Tags: react-router, mobx, mobx-react

After migration from Mobx 5 to Mobx 6 for some unknown reason, components stopped rerendering when router path is changed. `routerStore5` seems like its not `observable` even if its decorated by it. State inside `routerStore5` is changing, but components dont react for this state change. In Mobx 5 it worked fine but in new Mobx it does not. Is there some problem with package compatibility?

this connect is used as decorator for components which should have access to Mobx store

```
export function componentConnect(target) {
   return inject('stores')(withTheme(observer(target)));
}
```

Router store is accessible via connect above

```
  export class RouterStore {
  @observable routerStore5: RouterStore5;

  constructor() {
    const routerStore = new RouterStore5();
    const router = createRouter(routes, {
      defaultRoute: 'home',
      queryParamsMode: 'loose'
    });
    router.usePlugin(mobxPlugin(routerStore));
    router.usePlugin(browserPlugin({ useHash: false }));
    makeObservable(this);
    this.routerStore5 = routerStore;
    this.routerStore5.router.start();
  }
}
```

Here is list of used npm packages:

```
"router5": "^8.0.1",
"router5-plugin-browser": "^8.0.1",
"react-router5": "^8.0.1",
"mobx": "^6.1.8",
"mobx-react": "^7.1.0",
"mobx-router5": "^4.3.0",
"mobx-utils": "^6.0.3",
```

Comment: As far as i know the newest version of mobx does not require @ Annotations anymore. Look into that here: https://idanlevi2.medium.com/react-with-mobx-6-with-persist-and-without-decorators-bd7e5a0578d6